# Eclipse: Invalid maximum heap size:

Tags: eclipse, macos, heap-size

I'm getting error messages on Eclipse (Mac):

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx5120m-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/local/keystore/JavaKeyStore.jks-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit-Dtls.key.store=/usr/local/keystore/JavaKeyStore.jks-Dtls.trusted.store=/usr/local/keystore/JavaKeyStore.jks-Dawsmock.directory=/ijmeang/elis/s3-mock-Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/workspace/workspace-eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0-Dcatalina.home=/Library/Tomcat-Dwtp.deploy=/usr/local/workspace/workspace-eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Tomcat/endorsed
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

How can I fix this?

Here are the arguments on Eclipse:

> -Dcatalina.base="/usr/local/workspace/workspace-eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="/usr/local/Tomcat-7.0.6.9" -Dwtp.deploy="/usr/local/workspace/workspace-eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="/usr/local/Tomcat-7.0.6.9/endorsed" -Xss768m -Xmx5120m -XX:MaxPermSize=5120m -DmasterPropertiesLinux

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to decrease your value of `-Xmx5120m`, as described here:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

*Some JVMs put restrictions on the total amount of memory available on the heap.*

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what Java are you using. If you are using 32 bit Java you may not be able to use more than 2GB.